# Elastic beanstalk Django admin css not loading

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using Django 1.11.6, python 3.6.2

**Short summary: static files are collected correctly on server but only one app's sub directory is served, the admin's static files return as 404.**

Running the local development server everything works as expected. After deploying to my EB instance none of the static files for the admin app load. If i run `eb ssh` and look around on the server I can see the collected static folder, along with all the different app's subfolders. The files are all there where I'd expect. The links produced on the django front-end map in a sensible way to these paths, it's just that anything in static/admin returns a 404, while the files in static/entities work fine.

Testing paths on the front end:

```
/static/admin/css/base.css (404)
/static/entities/style.css (works)
```

On server, all collected files in static look fine:

```
/opt/python/current/app/static/admin/css
/opt/python/current/app/static/entities
```

No idea why one sub directory is server fine but the others return 404s.

From my django.config

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "spf.settings"
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app:$PYTHONPATH"
    "ALLOWED_HOSTS": ".elasticbeanstalk.com"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: spf/wsgi.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"
...

03_collectstatic:
  command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

Running the collectstatic command locally produces the correct static folder with the same subdirectories for each app too.

Comment: The resulting files and permissions on the server, identical between the three folders where only 'entities' is served correctly.

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Nov  8 11:22 admin
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov  8 11:22 entities 
    drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Nov  8 11:22 s3direct
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sheepish self-answer here:
In the AWS configuration for my eb instance I had set some static file aliases to serve directly from one of my sub apps. (Look under configuration->Software Configuration->Static Files). These aliases override any wsgi settings you may have in your django application. :)